# R - compare create logical vector

Tags: r, vector

I have 2 vectors, I want to show logic if elements in vector z are equal to any elements in vector x.

```
 z <- rep(c("AA","AB","AC","AD","AE"), 40)  
 x <- c("AA","AD","BB")  
 z == x
```

I use z == x but the True False values are not correct.
Warning shows, "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `%in%` (see `?"%in%"` for details):

```
z %in% x

head(z %in% x)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```